# "Ponder about" or just "ponder"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

Which is correct?

> 1. He was pondering about the meaning of life.
> 2. He was pondering the meaning of life.

Comment: ["Are you pondering what I'm pondering, Pinky?"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-xrnIXQ3iQ&t=5m3s) - "I think so, Brain - but then I would have to know what pondering **is**, wouldn't I?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common preposition is actually [ponder **over**](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ponder%20on,ponder%20about,ponder%20over,ponder%20upon&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

There's no difference in meaning, though some may think *upon* is dated and/or formal.

---

But in fact OP's second example (with no preposition at all) is [by far the most common usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ponder%20on%20the,ponder%20about%20the,ponder%20over%20the,ponder%20upon%20the,ponder%20the&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

In most contexts where no preposition is used, one can directly replace *ponder* with *think **about***, but *think **on***, *think **over***, and *think **upon*** don't normally work so well. This may lead some people to assume that *ponder* somehow "includes" the word *about*, so they find *ponder about* tautologous.

Answer (score 5):

The second would be better.

As for the first, "ponder" is usually followed by either "upon" or "on," the latter being less formal and more common.

The meaning of "ponder (on)" is "think about." This is why the Preposition "about" is normally confused with it.

Comment: Let me ponder that. :^) Of course, one could always say, quite simply, "I ponder." However (same as with many other verbs), that doesn't make for a very interesting or descriptive sentence. BTW, I'm not arguing – merely pondering out loud...

Comment: "Ponder upon" does sound pretty fancy. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

After pondering on (chewing on) the phrases, I guess that PONDER ON is typical of common English. 'Ponder upon' reminds me of very formal scene i.e a lawyer in a court of law.

Comment: Did you review previous answers before posting yours?