# "Typical of" or "typical for"?

Tags: word-usage

#### Background

Reading this [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72403/ponder-about-or-just-ponder/139612#139612), I realized that I had a tendency to use *"typical **for**"* rather than *"typical **of**"*.

After a quick research, reading through several sources on the web, I found that the more I read, the more I got confused. I felt like there is no established rules to state which one is more appropriate, in which occasion.

I even found the two usages in the same [BBC's article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/entertainment/arts_and_culture/8536205.stm),

> "The painting is a little a-typical **for** Van Gogh because of the many people appearing on it but also very typical because of the prominent role for the mill."
>
> "But he added that other elements of the the work, with its bright colours lathered roughly on the canvas, was typical **of** Van Gogh's style at the time he was living in Paris."

The searches for "typical of" and "typical for" here (EL&U) both returned substantial results, though "typical of" appears to be in favor.

#### Confusion

Trying to make sense of it, I was about to conclude that I should use "of" when the typicality is something *intrinsic* (a property or a character of what was talked about), and use "for" when such typicality should be viewed *extrinsically*. As these two examples from [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/typical),

> *This meal is typical of local cookery*. (intrinsic)
> *A typical working day for me begins at 7.30.* (extrinsic)

But soon I felt abash when I found someone mentioned question 7 in this [English Grammar Test, Elementary Level # 71](http://www.english-test.net/esl/learn/english/grammar/ei091/esl-test.php#seven),

> Such bad behavior is typical .......... the spoiled child.
>
> a) for
> b) with
> c) about
> d) of

The question was listed under *"british vs. american english"*, implying that each dialect prefers one usage over another. But I have a feeling that it might turn out to be untrue.

Is there any good rule of thumb for the usage of **typical for** vs. **typical of**?

Comment: All your examples with people use **typical for**, and with abstractions use **typical of**. I don't know whether this is a rule or not.

Comment: @PeterShor, thanks. That is precisely the way I considered them (I thought of them as actors and non-actors) before I abstracted the concept into intrinsic vs. extrinsic.

Comment: If it is a rule, it certainly is not a rigid one … you can easily find exceptions in both directions with Google.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say 'That's typical of him' would be far more common than the alternative.

However, in 'This meal is typical of local cookery', 'is typical of' can be replaced by 'is a typical example of'.

While in 'This meal is typical for the area', 'is typical for' can be replaced by 'is representative of what can be found [produced] in/by'.

Usage does seem rather unpredictable. Perhaps 'That's [just] typical of him' should be regarded as an idiomatic usage, and the two substitution-tests above taken as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

You intrinsic/extrinsic test seems to describe how I handle the of/for issue with *typical*.  Here's a look at the relative frequencies of the two constructions.  [image: Google Ngram Viewernter image description here]